# Quartz.net Setup for stored procedures and more

Tags: sql-server, quartz.net

Quartz.net and me don't seem to think the same way. Please help. 
I'll have Quartz running as a Windows Service. 
I'll have an Ado Jobstore setup on my SQL server. 
I'll have the connection string setup that allows Quartz to access the jobstore. 
I'll have a trigger job data map (stored in the jobstore?).

I see that I can set a Job-name, and can have Job Data Map key/value pairs that I can store for example a stored proc name and maybe a param. So far so good. I also see that I can write code that will implement iJob and in it grab the key/values from the context. My code could then call the stored proc with standard ADO code. I could do a similar thing with a webservice name and param, where my custom code would call the service.

Here are my questions: 
1) Do I really have to create a separate piece of code to execute the stored proc or web service? I would think something as sophisticated as Quartz would be able to "natively" handle calls to stored procs, web services, maybe execute ftp commands, etc. Am I looking for a no-code solution when I shouldn't be?

2) Assuming I do have to write my own "do the work" code, where do I put that code? Do I compile into a DLL and place it somewhere? How do I tell Quartz where to look for my DLLs?  And how do I associate the Job-Name in the config with my class in my DLL? Do I just use the Job-Name setting as the actual name of my class?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation and found no references to the folder where the DLL needs to be placed in order to be picked up. All references I found referred to having remote access to the DLL, not direct access.  If you put your answers as a separate post I can mark them as answers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you still have to write separate job classes.

2) All your class has to do is implement the IJob interface and the scheduler will pick it up. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is a scheduler, it's all it does and it does it well. It does not "natively" handle calls to stored procs, web services, or ftp commands. You have to write the code to do that in your class that implements IJob and is instantiated by Quartz on the schedule you specify.

The best thing to do is to create a separate class library (DLL) that you will reference from your app which creates an instance of Quartz scheduler and provide it with a fully qualified name of the class it needs to instantiate (e.g. MyLibrary.MyNameSpace.MyClass) and it will instantiate that class on the schedule and execute your code found in the overriden `Execute()` method of your class...

It's that simple...